# Linked Lists C program bugs

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I'm having a problem debugging a linked lists program. It just crashes after the first few lines I figured it was probably a scanf problem and double checked but I still can't get it to run. It crashes in the middle of a function that creates a new node. Here is the code of the function and the main.

```
std* CreateNode()
{       
    std *newnd;
    char nm[20];
    double g;
    printf("\nCreating node\n");
    printf("\nEnter the student's name:\n");
    scanf("%s", &nm);
    printf ("\nEnter the student's GPA:\n");
    scanf("%lf", &g);
    strcpy( (newnd->name), nm);
    newnd->GPA = g;
    newnd->next = NULL;
    return newnd;
}

int main()
{
    list_head = (std*) malloc( sizeof(std) );
    list_tail=(std*) malloc( sizeof(std) );
    list_tail=(std*) malloc( sizeof(std) );

    list_head=CreateNode();
    A=CreateNode();
    B=CreateNode();
    C=CreateNode();
    PrintList(list_head);
    InsertBeg(A);
    InsertEnd(B);
    InsertMiddle(C);
    PrintList(list_head);
    SearchStudent();
    DeleteMiddle();
    DeleteEnd();
    DeleteBeg();
    PrintList(list_head);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program it stops executing right after I enter the gpa.

Any help would be very welcome I've tried everything I can think of.
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare

```
std* newnd;
```

however you never allocate memory for it before you try to access it's members.

```
std* newnd = malloc( sizeof *newnd  );
```

Comment: Better: `std* newnd = (std*)malloc(sizeof(newnd));`

Comment: @JoséX. Don't cast the result of malloc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: sizeof is an operator not a function. no need for parens

Comment: @SteveCox That is incorrect. In some cases you need parentheses. A good habit is to always include them.

Comment: you need parens only to resolve operator precidence, like all other operators.

Comment: @self according to the page I linked, you only need them when it is a type

Comment: @clcto For consistency it is better to always go with the parentheses. Omitting them can cause an error, but always including them cannot.

Comment: @clcto: you're right, I'm confusing languages here, in C the cast is not needed.

Comment: @self including the parens for the expression variant is equivalent to including them for any of the other 8 unary operators. e.g. ++(var)

Comment: @SteveCox That comparison is invalid since sizeof operator has a mode where the parenthesis are mandatory regardless of the actual code.

Comment: Enough of this. It is a coding-style. Just follow the same style as your team and everything will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

in you program,

```
std *newnd;
```

is a pointer where did you allocate memory to it? you used the variable without allocating memory to it in

```
 strcpy( (newnd->name), nm);
 newnd->GPA = g;  
 newnd->next = NULL;
```

this results in program to crash. so allocate memory before using a variable.